# Two short-lived threads vs. Executor

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java-threads

I have only two short-lived tasks to run in the background upon the start of the application. Would it make sense to use a thread for each task or an Executor, for instance, a single thread executor to submit these two tasks.

Does it make sense to create two threads that die quickly as opposed to having a single threaded executor waiting for tasks throughout the lifecycle of the application when there are none?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One big benefit of using a threadpool is that you avoid the scenario where you have some task that you perform repeatedly then, if something goes wrong with that task that causes the thread to hang, you're at risk of losing a thread every time the task happens, resulting in running the application out of threads. If your threads only run once on startup then it seems likely that risk wouldn't apply to your case.

You could still use Executor, but shut it down once your tasks have both run. It might be preferable to use Futures or a CompletionService over raw threads.

Comment: doing the 2 phase termination as specified here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Answer (score 1):

If you do this more than once in your application, `ThreadPoolExecutor` is definitely worth a look.

One benefit is the pooling of threads. This releaves the runtime to create and destroy OS objects every time you need a thread. Additionally you get control of the amount of threads spawned - but this seems not the big issue for you - and threads running/done.

But if you actually really only spawn two threads over the runtime of your application, the executors may be oversized, but they are nevertheless very comfortable to work with.

Since Nathan added Futures, there is also `Timer` and `TimerTask`. Also very convenient for "Fire and Forget" type of background action :-).